# Check the installation date of Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp-sp3

Is it possible to check, using Python programming languque, the time on which the operating system is installed ? Mainly,  I am interested in Windows XP platform. I wonder if there is such an API in python or any trick to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Windows registry:

```
import _winreg as reg
from datetime import datetime

key = reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion')
secs = reg.QueryValueEx(key, 'InstallDate')[0] # This is stored as a UNIX timestamp
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(secs)
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError:[WinError 2] The system can not find the file specified`

Comment: @begueradj: Check if that key exists in your registry. (I don't have an XP install, but this is said to work elsewhere).

Comment: The path you gave me is valid on my computer

Comment: I removed the 'r' just before `'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...` you wrote, so it works now for me. I am going to use your solution because it runs more quickly and i can use the date in a variable for later needs in my Python program. Thank you for the help. Also, I am using Python-3.4.1. So I had to change _winreg to winreg as the official documenation asks me.

Comment: @begueradj: Ah. I wrote the answer assuming you were using Python 2.x.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just precised my comment for people who are using Python 3-4.1. Otherwise in Python 2.x no change to be done on your solution

Answer (score 2):

This isn't python specific, but you can find this via the `systeminfo` and `find` commands.

```
>systeminfo | find /i "original"
Original Install Date:     7/27/2011, 3:06:49 PM
```

The string `original` applies if the installation locale is English.

You can wrap this in an `os.system` call

```
>>> os.system("""systeminfo | find /i "original" """)
Original Install Date:     7/27/2011, 3:06:49 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
import os

info = os.popen('cmd /k systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"').read();
print info
#Original Install Date:     5/12/2014, 9:06:04 AM
```

I am yet to look into the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) package, but it is the recommended option. os will get the job done though.

Comment: I would just read the output of `cmd /k systeminfo` and parse it in Python (loop through the lines and output the one which starts with 'Original Install Date'). You can obtain all the output of a process using `subprocess.check_output`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getInstallDate():
  cache = os.popen2("SYSTEMINFO")
  info = cache[1].read()
  label = "Original Install Date:" 
  return info.split(label)[-1].split("\n")[0].strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import platform
print platform.system(), platform.release()
```

Comment: `>>> print platform.system(), platform.release()` outputs `Windows 7`.

Comment: This prints me the OS and its version

Comment: `>>> print platform.system(), platform.release()
Linux 3.11.0-23-generic` no date information